# FaceDetector not detecting faces with front camera

Tags: android, camera, face-detection

I am experiencing a strange issue with the `FaceDetector` from the Android SDK. The code below is working fine and detecting faces correctly when using the back camera, but no matter what, when the picture is from the front camera, no face is detected.

```
FaceDetector.Face[] faces = new FaceDetector.Face[1];
FaceDetector faceDetector = new FaceDetector(width, height, 1);
int facesFound = faceDetector.findFaces(picture, faces);
Log.d(TAG, "Face found: "+(facesFound == 1));
```

I am trying to find an explanation for this, but I haven't come to any conclusion. I have even tried to clean the meta-data of the picture, in case the FaceDetector was set to not detect faces in pictures coming from the front camera.

Comment: There are definitely devices that do not detect faces from the FFC. What does [`getMaxNumDetectedFaces()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getMaxNumDetectedFaces%28%29) return? And what device is this?

Comment: It returns 0 - it's a Huawei Ascend P6. I don't understand the meaning of this. Why can't I do what I want with the captured image? And how does the face detector knows how many faces can be detected?

Comment: My apologies -- I was focused on the camera's own face detection logic, not using `FaceDetector` explicitly.

Comment: No worries, thanks for your time. I will go for the OpenCV libs then

Answer (score 2):

There are various factors that could be the cause of the problem. Here are some I've run into:

- The bitmap is not upright
- The bitmap is not in 565 pixel format
- The image is poor quality (too dark, too noisy, poor resolution, obscured by a finger, etc.)